# Why do lp and lpr return unauthorized?

Tags: ubuntu, cups, lpr

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 with latest updates.

Here are my system's protections for lp and lpr.

```
root@steamboy:/usr/bin# ls -l lp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13540 2011-09-12 10:41 lp
root@steamboy:/usr/bin# ls -l lpr
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13540 2011-09-12 10:41 lpr
```

Only if I sudo can I print something at the command line, else
I can unauthorized.

I do have an smb printer with username and password embedded, but I believe this problem occurred during one of the 10.04 updates. So my question is what would cause lp or lpr to return Unauthorized?

```
ics@steamboy:~/icsdev$ lp x.tmp
lp: Unauthorized
ics@steamboy:~/icsdev$ lpr x.tmp
lpr: Unauthorized
```

(x.tmp is a real file.)

The real stumper is gedit will allow me to print.

Comment: Is selinux enabled? What are the selinux restrictions on lp, lpr, and the associated files? (ls -Z)

Comment: I believe it is not enabled. I did not install it, and there is no /etc/selinux directory. Also, the "unauthorized" message started happening after an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try checking your printers.conf file and comment out the line:

```
AuthInfoRequired negotiate
```

it's a default setting in ubuntu

Comment: hmm maybe you could check the cups.conf file and check for local user printing permissions. also, it could be that the user trying to print doesnt have read permissions to the cups.conf file. if so, `chmod 644 /etc/cups/client.conf` .
gl!

Comment: AuthInfoRequired not present in printers.conf

Comment: /etc/cups/client.conf not present.